# Using date and timestamp as partition key and clustering key

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a table that stores system activities. The data model has the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE activities {
  id UUID,
  json text,
  activity_date Date,
  activity_time Timestamp,
  activity_type Text,
  Primary Key(activity_date, activity_type, activity_time)
}
```

The potential use cases that the above table would be serving are

1. Find the events that were generated for a given date
2. Find the events that were generated for a given date and activity_type
3. Find the events that were generated for a given date and activity_type within a given time frame.

The above data model is vulnerable to a bug where if 2 activities with same activity type are inserted at the same millisecond, one of them could override the other. That's because casssandra guarantees the timestamp uniqueness upto a millisecond.

Another table in the database had a similar structure and we saw records overriding each other twice. This has happened 2 times in 2 years. Although, the probability is low, but still possible to mess up data integrity.

In order to overcome this issue, we could potentially add an `IF NOT EXISTS` clause to the insert query, which would cause 1 insert to fail while the other one would succeed if such a case ever arises.

However, I would like to understand of there is anything else that can be done here?

Any thing else that cassandra could offer which we're missing?

Is it a case of a badly designed data model? But given the queries, we didn't have any more columns to add to the keys.

Comment: Your question is very much valid, I think according to me adding eventId(id in your case) to the clustering column will give a uniqueness. That should be the only solution.

Answer (score 4):

In general if you have maybe conflicting timestamps - you could go and use timeuuids instead of timestamps. They should be unique and you can always get back the timestamps from them.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html

Some other notes:

- do you use your UUID you defined?
- you should add entropy to your partition key, maybe ((activity_date, activity_type), activity_time), because only having activity_date as partition key will lead to hotspots

Comment: I think timeuuids would be our choice as it ensures conflict free timestamp generation. Thanks for the suggestion. We are thinking of dropping the UUID column now as its not used.